# Error while install appium in windows 8, Couldn't find java 'jar' executable on your path.Please ensure it is present, I have set variable for java

Tags: appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0D1s.png)

I have installed appium in windows 8, Getting error as Not find  jar executable file in your path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to  simply  add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.xx.x_\bin` to Windows' PATH variable.

That is the location where jar.exe is located on Windows (yours may differs, depending on JDK version, etc.)
You'd have to start a new command prompt (assuming you're using Windows'cmd) for the new PATH variable to reflect the change.